# How can one have their wishes fulfilled

Tags: stotra

I am going through a really bad phase and need help. I have tried various remedies including various fasts which did not work.

Does anyone know of any stotras which’s can fulfil one’s wishes? Ways to fulfil the wish using the stotra would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are having a bad time, then you don't need stotram, gods, or wishes getting fulfilled through magic. You need - enlightenment. The understanding of who you are and a lot of meditation. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

To fullfil wishes one has to make Gods/Goddesses joyous. This is very difficult without production procurement and presentation in a form applicable to deity.

To fullfil wishes one can loose some assets of his own.

To fullfil wishes one can eliminate enemies who blocked it by a method called abhicharika prayogam.

To fullfil wishes one can take more efforts and dedicate a portion for Godly activities periodically by sankalpam.

But wishes are a level below happiness and Divine attributes of a holy person.

YOU CAN WISH within limitations only.